# x86 assembly 64-bit values with 32-bit program

Tags: assembly, x86, nasm, 32bit-64bit, endianness

If we multiply two very large 32-bit values the result can end up in registers EDX and EAX, with EDX holding the higher bits.

- How do we perform operations on these 64-bit values and print them to the display?

I figured storing them was simply a matter of reserving two 32-bit memory spaces next to each other and storing EAX first then EDX second in the next 32-bit space. So with little-endianness we would have the lowest bit from EAX first and the highest bit from EDX held last across the two 32-bit memory spaces.

- Is this right?
- If so, what abstract thinking do we have to do after that in order to operate on the number?
- Also could the 32-bit `printf` function be used somehow to display the value using only the original specifiers, such as "%d", "%u" or "%x"? Or do we have to make our own assembly process to print the value?

Comment: Most 32-bit C compilers/libraries support a type `long long` for 64-bit values, and their `printf` functions use `ll` (or sometimes `L`) as a size modifier for this type (so you could use specifiers like `"%lld"` or `"%llu"` or `"%llx"`.)

Comment: Yes, that's right.  Look at how compilers add `uint64_t` function args with `add`/`adc`, e.g. `gcc -m32 -O2` - https://godbolt.org/.  ([How to remove "noise" from GCC/clang assembly output?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38552116))

Comment: For additions/subtractions/comparisons, use the `adc` and `sbb` instructions.  For multiplication and division, implement long multiplication/division as taught in elementary school, but with 32 bit "digits."  I recommend you implement all the basic operations (addition, subtraction, multiplication, division) to get familiar with the general idea.  The rest will be very easy.  Oh and for bit shifts, use `shld` and `shrd` of course.

Comment: I guess what I really want to know is how does printf print a 64 bit value when we are working with 32 bit registers? What would that look like in assembly code? How would someone create that functionality themselves?

Comment: @Tim As an example of the **conversion from 64bit binary number to decimal digits** in 32bit assembly look at my macro [StoQD](https://euroassembler.eu/maclib/cpuext32.htm#StoQD),

Comment: I think GCC will just emit a `call` to a helper function for `u64 / 10` and `% 10`, but you can single-step into those functions if you're curious.  Related: [Why should EDX be 0 before using the DIV instruction?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38416593) shows how to use non-zero EDX to chain `div` instructions for extended-precision division like u64 / u32.  (As part of the algorithm shown in [How do I print an integer in Assembly Level Programming without printf from the c library? (itoa, integer to decimal ASCII string)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46301894))

Comment: Also [Displaying numbers with DOS](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45904075) shows 32-bit division in 16-bit mode, which is the same problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your observations about storing the 64-bit value from EDX:EAX are correct.

Further calculations that are easy enough are addition and subtraction:

```
add  eax, ebx    ; EDX:EAX + ECX:EBX
adc  edx, ecx

sub  eax, ebx    ; EDX:EAX - ECX:EBX
sbb  edx, ecx
```

> I guess what I really want to know is how does printf print a 64 bit value when we are working with 32 bit registers? What would that look like in assembly code? How would someone create that functionality themselves?

From your comment it is clear that you really would like to do the conversion from 64-bit number EDX:EAX into a string of characters yourself.
My answer at
[How to print a multiplication result in EDX:EAX in Assembly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75941444/how-to-print-a-multiplication-result-in-edxeax-in-assembly/75972277#75972277) shows how to do just that.
For additional info about the general approach to converting, be sure to read the answer for which a link was provided there. Don't feel intimidated by the mention of (old) DOS. Many principles don't change that much as technology evolves...

Comment: Awesome, Thanks!